# Paste result based on the Rank of Column values

Tags: excel, vba

I have this code and its working perfectly the problem i have been facing is the code is not pasting the result according to the RANKS.

I want to add the first `1` to the value which is highest in the rank then to 2nd highest then 3rd highest and so on... the last `1` will be added to the value which is lowest in rank.

code will find their rank in the range, based on that rank add 1 in the column next to it. do it until added 1 to every cell (Except 0).

I know for the final result, the rank doesn't matter. But it is necessary to add the rank logic.

you help will be greatly appreciated.

```
Sub SlowRange()

    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = Sheet1.Cells(Sheet1.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = Sheet1.Range("A2:A" & LastRow)
    
    Dim c As Range
    For Each c In rg.Cells
        If c.Value <> 0 Then
            c.Offset(, 1).Value = 1
        'Else
        '    c.Offset(, 1).Value = Empty
        End If
    Next c

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: What do you mean ranks? Like, highest number first? So, B14 then B17 then B3 and so on?

Comment: Yes you are right @Christofer Weber

Comment: Wait so what's the point if they're all going to be 1's? Or do you want it to go 1,2,3,4 etc in the order of largest to smallest? 
`I know for the final result, the rank doesn't matter. But it is necessary to add the rank logic` makes it sound like some sort of school project, otherwise it's pointless to do that. If it is, you shouldn't be getting other people to do it for you.

Comment: the point is this thing can be done through sorting function but how to  do this without sorting and its been years when i complete my graduation. @Simon

Comment: Is anything else happening in between assigning one to column B?

Comment: Yes!  that is first 1 will be added to the highest value then to 2nd highest then 3rd highest and so on and last 1 will be added to the value which is lowest one in  rank @norie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this code.

```
Sub WriteRanks()
    ' 226 - 27 Apr 2021
    
    Dim Rng         As Range            ' range to rank
    Dim Arr         As Variant          ' numbers to rank
    Dim ArrNew      As Variant          ' tie-broken Ar
    Dim Ct          As Long             ' temporary column
    Dim R           As Long             ' loop counter: array rows
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")           ' change to suit
        ' from row 2 in column A to the end of column A
        Set Rng = .Range(.Cells(2, "A"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
        Arr = Rng.Value
        ReDim ArrNew(1 To UBound(Arr))
        For R = 1 To UBound(Arr)
            ' add a tie breaker: 10th digit
            ArrNew(R) = Arr(R, 1) + (R / (10 ^ 10))
        Next R
        
        With .UsedRange                 ' find a blank column on the right
            Ct = .Column + .Columns.Count
        End With
        Set Rng = Rng.Offset(0, Ct)
        Rng.Value = Application.Transpose(ArrNew)    ' fill the helper column
        
        For R = 1 To UBound(Arr)
            If Arr(R, 1) Then .Cells(R + 1, "B").Value = WorksheetFunction.Rank(ArrNew(R), Rng, 0)
        Next R

        ' delete the helper column
        .Columns(Rng.Column).EntireColumn.Delete
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
End Sub
```

Observe that the tie breaker adds R * 1/10000000000 (=10 ^ 10) to each number. This is supposed to be an insignificant digit but since it is multiplied by the row number, it may become significant in row 100,000. The balance here depends upon how many rows you have and how many digits in your numbers. With 0.0869652 (7 digits) it should still be OK till row 1,000 but at row 100,000 you may wish to switch to `10 ^ 12`.

The tie breaker doesn't affect your original numbers, just their ranking. when the same number occurs more than once.

Comment: I have used the code which is working perfect but it does not skip the 0 value. @Variatus

Comment: It should not include the 0 value for ranking @Variatus

Comment: I have modified the code to not rank zero values.